# Is supply current lower than output current in voltage regulator circuits?

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics

Say I have a 5v linear voltage regulator circuit with a supply voltage of 24v.

If the 5v citcuit is using 20amps how many amps will the 24v supply need to deliver? Or will the current be the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A linear voltage regulator acts pretty much like an intelligent resistor setting it's value in such way that the voltage behind it is regulated to the wanted voltage.

Because of that, the current at the input is almost the same as the current of the output. It will be higher because the linear regulator needs some current as well to do its thing.

This also means, that a linear voltage regulator is wasting all the energy to heat, which in your case would turn to be a whopping 380W ((Vin-Vout)*Iin), so that would be a really beefy linear regulator and require a lot of cooling. I'd say it's very impractical.

For a case like that a switching regulator will probably be the better choice, as it converts the voltage with a certain efficiency. In good designs it can be very high, 90% or higher is achievable. That means that the input power is higher than the output power but the current would be lower (for a step down converter):

$$ \eta = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} \rightarrow P_{in} = \frac{P_{out}}{\eta}$$

In your example with 90% efficiency the input power would be just 111W (instead of 480W for the linear regulator). And the current on the 24V side would turn out to be just 4.63A.

Switching regulators have their downsides as well, like a higher output voltage ripple.

Answer (score 3):

The input current of a linear regulator will be slightly higher than the output current, the difference being the current required to operate the regulator itself.

For a switching regulator, the *power* into the regulator will be slightly greater than the *power* output of the regulator.

Answer (score -1):

If the LDO was operating at 100% efficiency, then the power out would equal the power in, i.e. 
$$P = 5V * 20A = 24V * I_{IN}$$ or

$$I_{IN} = \frac{5V*20A}{24V} = 4.17 A$$

But unfortunately, LDO's have terrible efficiency, and it gets worse as the difference between the input and output voltages increase.

$$ƞ = \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{5V}{24V} = 0.208$$

So the actual required input current =

$$ \frac{I_{IN}}{ƞ} = \frac{4.17A}{.208} = 20 A$$

So the input current equals the output current after all.

Note that if you were using a switching regulator, with a much higher efficiency of 85%, this would be

$$ \frac{I_{IN}}{ƞ} = \frac{4.17A}{.85} = 4.90 A$$

What a difference.

Another way of doing this same calculation the output and input powers:

$$ P_{OUT} = V_{OUT} * I_{OUT} = 5V * 20A = 100 W$$

$$P_{IN} = \frac{P_{OUT}}{ƞ} = \frac{100W}{.85} = 117.6 W$$

$$I_{IN} = \frac{P_{IN}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{117.6W}{24V} = 4.90 A$$

Comment: Hmm efficiency is normally defined as a ratio of powers, or is it not? And for a LDO it can only be turned into a ratio of voltages because the current on the input and output are the same.

Comment: @Arsenal See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator#Efficiency_and_heat_dissipation) where the formula I used is derived.

Comment: Yeah, like I said efficiency is defined as a ratio of powers and can be reduced to a ratio of voltages for a LDO because the input and output current are the same. Using this to show that input and output currents are the same because efficiency is low is sort of backwards and self-proofing. (I found it rather confusing, but I know how a LDO works - so maybe it's helpful for others, but might be misleading if someone calculates efficiency for something else and just uses a voltage ratio)

Answer (score -2):

One way to calculate the Iin of the system is based on the simple efficiency = Pout/Pin equation. Pin = Vin * Iin and Pout = Vout * Iout. So assuming that your linear regulator is 60% efficient. You can now solve for the Iin needed for this design.

Iin=(5Vout*20Iout)/(Vin*.6) => 6.94Amps

Comment: Linear regulators will use the same current (plus a little overhead) that they deliver, thus the efficiency is based on how much voltage is being dropped over them.

Comment: The efficiency is determined by the input and output voltages and current; it's not a property of the regulator.  24 V in at 20 A to produce 5 V out at 20 A dissipates 380 W to produce 100 W, so is 21% efficient.